# Login credentials for puppeteer running on a rocker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, puppeteer

I am running puppeteer on a docker container in headless mode to test our website. The first page is the login page. The puppeteer script and docker files are stored in an internal git repo. What is a good way of securely storing the login credentials?

Obviously not as a file in the fit repo. Docker secrets is an option, what are some other options? I need puppeteer to read them without any user intervention.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the credentials as environment variables to your docker container. The following line starts the docker container and passes the variables `LOGIN_USER` and `LOGIN_PASSWORD` from your host to your docker environment. That way, you specify them as environment variables inside your host system, but you do specify them inside your code or repository.

**Starting Docker**

```
docker run -e LOGIN_USER LOGIN_PASSWORD [...]
```

**Inside the container**

Inside your container, you then use the variable by accessing `process.env.LOGIN_USER` and `process.env.LOGIN_PASSWORD` like this (example using [`page.type`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pagetypeselector-text-options)):

```js
page.type('#input-field', process.env.LOGIN_USER);
```

**Setting the environment variables**

There are multiple options to set the environment variables. You can either set the permanently (in case you want to run multiple docker containers) or only for a single command. Check out [this answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/58828) for more information.